# Как переименовать все файлы в ubuntu?

Tags: bash

В папке у меня есть .amr файлы с разными именами. Мне нужно переименовать все, в  таком порядке

```
0001.wav
0002.wav
0003.wav
```

и.т.д.
как я могу это сделать в терминале ubuntu?

Comment: там может не переименовать, а конвертировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот таким скриптом это можно сделать:

```
a=1
for i in *.amr; do
  new=$(printf "%04d.wav" "$a") #04 pad to length of 4
  mv -i -- "$i" "$new"
  let a=a+1
done
```

Comment: Спосибо большое!!! Получилась!!! Вы очень помогли!!!

Answer (score 0):

`rename old new`

Многие дистрибутивы содержат этот perl скрипит.

**Ссылки**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577767/get-the-perl-rename-utility-instead-of-the-built-in-rename